# git config --global core.editor doesn't work

Tags: git, emacs

To get around the problem of emacs's Ctrl-G crashing `git commit` and `git rebase`, I tried the fix provided in http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2012-05/msg00233.html

However, `git rebase -i` always calls the "old" emacs, even though I have specified to use the shell script. I have also tried to use /usr/bin/vim, but to no avail. Whatever I set, I still get emacs.

```
$ git config --global --list
user.name=xxx
user.email=xxx
push.default=simple
core.editor=/usr/bin/vim
color.ui=auto
```

`/usr/bin/vim` exists and works when called from the command line.

I also tried to edit the `~/.gitconfig` file directly, edit the `.git/config` in my project and edit the `/usr/etc/gitconfig`, all with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Argh, I had an environment variable

```
GIT_EDITOR=emacs
```

which screwed this up. Unsetting that made it all work. Seems like this should be in the git documentation.
(Which it is, see below. Doh!)

Comment: It *is* in the git documentation. From [`git help config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config): `core.editor` Commands such as `commit` and `tag` that lets you edit messages by launching an editor uses the value of this variable when it is set, and the environment variable `GIT_EDITOR` is not set. See `git-var(1)`. And from [`git help var`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-var.html): The order of preference is the `$GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, then `core.editor` configuration, then `$VISUAL`, then `$EDITOR`, and then the default chosen at compile time, which is usually `vi`.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes, I found the `git help var` as well, when I discovered the environment variable and started looking through the docs. But for some reason, I didn't try `git help config`, but went straight to stackexchange, looking for this problem.